# Countable transitive model of ZFC and $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, ordinals

Let $\mathbb{M}$ be a countable transitive model of ZFC.

I understand that $\omega^\mathbb{M} = \omega$ but $\mathcal{P}(\omega)^\mathbb{M} \neq \mathcal{P}(\omega)$, for $\mathcal{P}(\omega)^\mathbb{M}$ is countable from an external point of view. So $\mathcal{P}(\omega)^\mathbb{M}$ is the set of all the subsets of $\omega$ that belongs to $\mathbb{M}$.

Here is where I get confused : how is it possible that some subset of $\omega$ do not belong to $\mathbb{M}$ ? After all, all the finite ordinals belong to $\mathbb{M}$ and $\mathbb{M}$ is a model of ZFC. Why is it that with the same ingredients (the finite ordinals) and with the same construction rules (the axioms of ZFC), we manage to build all the subsets of $\omega$ in $V$ but we are not able to do so in $\mathbb{M}$ ?

Comment: What's more it that $\mathbb{M}$ believes that it has **all** of the ordinals, and yet it has only countably many!

Comment: @Kyle: Or that $\omega_1^\Bbb M$ is a countable ordinal. Or so on and so forth.

Comment: @Asaf: Right, there are so many mind bending facts. It's incredible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here, I think, is that we don't build the sets. The universe is given to us, it is just there. Of course, we are able to prove that by iterating transfinitely the power set operation from $\varnothing$, we can end up with any given set. But the power set operation is in some sense atomic to the universe.

And this is the case when $V$ itself is not $L$, and we can define a subclass of $V$ which is also a model of $\sf ZFC$, but doesn't agree with $V$ on the power set of at least one ordinal (sometimes $\omega$, sometimes not, it doesn't matter). In fact, that is an even better question, suppose that $V=L[x]$ for some real number $x$. Then $V$ and $L$ disagree on $\mathcal P(\omega)$, even though both contain all the ordinals.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. In any model M, we can form any finite subset of ω, by applying the pairing and union axioms (relativized to M) a finite number of times. We can also form infinite subsets of ω using the subset axiom scheme - e.g. the set of even natural numbers. However, we can only do this countably many times - once for each formula φ. There is an uncountable number of subsets that we cannot 'build' this way, even though they are 'given' to us by P(ω). In V we can say these sets are each part of some V_α - but in neither V nor M can we 'build' them all without P(ω)

Comment: No. It is quite possible that $M$ is a countable model, and for every subset of $\omega$ which is in $M$, there is a formula (without parameters!) that defines it in $M$. The point is that a model is given to us, we are not building it. And if the model is countable, well, it has only countably many sets, in particular, only countably many subsets of $\omega$ are actually in the model. In this context where the model is transitive, it's easy to see that $V_\omega$ is the "correct" one, and that already includes all the finite subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: But there are certain sets which must exist in any model M we are given, right? That is, M contains sets that M 'believes' to be the empty set, the set P(∅), etc - since the existence of those sets can can proven from the axioms of ZFC, which M satisfies. However, it is possible for us to be given a (countable) model M that does not contain every subset of ω (as seen from 'outside' M), since we cannot prove that all of them must exist in every model M (as I described in my previous comment). Does that sound right, or is there still something that I'm missing?

Comment: @AaronHill: Yes, except that, again, there is some subtlety to what formulas can and will give you. And in different models of ZF, the same formula may define wildly different sets. And if we have a model whose $\omega$ is an uncountable set, what does it mean that a subset of $\omega$ "must exist in that model"?